# Generate reports through ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, crystal-reports, report, rdlc

I need to generate reports from database (billing forms for example) from ASP.NET interface. So I'm wondering which approach is better : Use Crystal Reports, reports based on RDLC or SQL Reporting Services ? I need to create an interface, which allows user to select data and through pre-created report definition generate that report. I want to use ASP.NET with AJAX, so it will act as a real application, but with no need for installation - and this is primary requirement.
So, if somebody knows which technology suits best those requirements...I will be grateful :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go for [DevExpress XtraReports](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/).

I have used it in the past in both windows forms and web forms; it costs few hundreds of bucks but with the package you also get plenty of other UI controls, or you spend less and only buy XtraReports. It pays off in a flash, main advantages in my opinion are:

- each report can be designed with a Visual Studio integrated designer and becomes a simple c# class, easy to instantiate and use, no magic and no external report definitions, all pure 100% .NET code;
- end user designed is royalty free and users are amazed by the power and quality of the designer, with Ribbon or classic UI, plenty of features;
- so many out of the box zero coding ready to use features like print preview, export to excel, pdf etc...

**Disclaimer:** I do not work for DevExpress, I am not paid by them, simply I am a satisfied customer and used their products before with joy and good results, we are now in the process of starting a major MVC application development in my company and we are buying licenses of their DXperience Enterprise subscription these days.

you are free to also evaluate or test Crystal Reports or similar reporting solutions offered by ActiveReports, Telerik etc, I can only speak about XtraReports because I used it a lot, Crystal I used in the past with Visual Studio 2003 but I was not so impressed by the designer and deployment was really a mess in windows forms... always missing some files and having errors on client machines...

Answer (score 0):

We use SQL Server Reporting services, it has a visual studio based designer, and it's free. The distribution is a little tricky - If your clients already have SQL Server installed, then there is a a good chance they will have the reporting framework installed. Otherwise you can get just about distribute the dll's with your application - although this takes a bit of digging.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [ActiveReports 6](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx). It provides great features and allows you to make almost unlimited customization to your report. For ASP.NET you can either opt for the standard edition which allows you to custom export your reports to different formats like PDF, Excel etc and display them to the users.

The professional edition provides you a webviewer control which allows you to display reports directly on the viewer and the user has the option to chose from PDF, HTML and FlashViewer format. In addition to this it also provides a silverlight based viewer control.

You may also want to check the [blogs](http://www.gcpowertools.info/) and the forums just in case you want to get more information about the product.

Thanks,
Sankalp (GrapeCity)

Comment: Hi - you seem to work for ActiveReports. Thanks for helping out here and answering the other question about your products. However the [house rules here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) are that you should identify yourself when recommending your own products. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't miss to take a look into [List & Label](http://www.combit.net/en/), too.
We've done some good projects with it!